# Javascript array showing 2 values in console, only 1 when accessed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript array of arrays.
When I print the array to the console I get:

```
console.log(my_array_of_arrays);


Array[2] ->, Array[2] ->,  
0: 678       0: 1168
1: 865       1: 1370
length: 2    length: 2
```

This shows that there are 2 items in both arrays.

Then when I access last item in the array by accessing either ".length" or my_array[1], it tells me that the array only has 1 item, and the 2nd item is undefined.

```
var my_array = my_array_of_arrays[1];
console.log(my_array, my_array.length, my_array[0], my_array[1]);


[1168, 1370], 1, 1168, undefined
```

As you can see this happens if I do it all in the same console log statement, so I know the array isn't changing.

What could be going on here, I am completely stumped.

**Edited for clarity**

Comment: Could you please post a link to a live example that demonstrates this, from e.g. jsbin.com?

Comment: Why aren't you doing : `console.log(my_array,my_array.length, my_array[0], my_array[1]);` on the second debug? is it from the same line, after the same events?

Comment: place function fully so we can analyze it

Comment: This totally looks like you've been messing around with `Array.prototype`, or are using some (poorly written) library which does that. What other scripts are in action in this context?

Comment: That is possible I suppse, (that i'm using Array.prototype). I am using the jQuery FullCalendar plugin. 
When I do a search I do find calls to Array.prototype.slice.call but they don't seem to be in the same scope as the array i'm trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that further down the function the value my_array[2] wasn't being set until after I called console.log().
However this has shown some weird behavior of console.log().
It doesn't necessarily show the live value of the array at the time of calling.

eg.

```
var my_array = [111];
console.log(my_array);
my_array[1] = 222;
```

This prints:

```
[111, 222]
```

When I was expecting it to print:

```
[111]
```

This means that console.log() doesn't always show the "live" representation of the real values at the time of the call.

However if I access a property on the array it will show the live values.

Example:

```
var my_array = [111];
console.log(my_array.length, my_array[1]);
my_array[1] = 222;
```

This prints as expected:

```
1, undefined
```

Guess I can't trust the console as well as I have been!

Answer (score 0):

From the console in Chrome

```
spo = [000,111]
(spo[0] == 000) //true
(spo[1] == 111) //true
```

I am not sure what else you can be doing = /

Comment: I know. The thing is it works fine for the rest of the arrays in my array of arrays. This is messing with my mind